# navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition is not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, geolocation

This is the code i am using for getting locations. But unfortunately it prints "failure call back " always.

```
 var location_timeout = setTimeout(function(){alert('failed');}, 10000);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            findInStore.isGeoLocationPos = position;
            clearTimeout(location_timeout);
            alert('Succ call back')
            findInStore.onDirectionLocation(event);
        },function(){clearTimeout(location_timeout);
        alert('failure call back');});
```

**Try**

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350033/geolocation-not-working-in-safari
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397585/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-sometimes-works-sometimes-doesnt
```

and few more. But none helps. getCurrentPosition call fails. Any suggestions? I am not good at this.

Answer (score 0):

Turn Wifi on on your computer and it will work. Safari use wifi to geolocalize your computer :-)